# How do I redirect client to a new page using Express post route?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to build a node/express webapp where I click a button which turns a `<div>` into a pdf, zip and password protect the pdf, email it to the recipient, and at the end generate a new page with the pdf so I can see that it rendered correctly.

I have everything working except generating the preview of the pdf. I am pretty new to node and http routes in general, so I know I am missing something obvious.

The form successfully sends the `<div>` to the server, the server converts it, zips it, and mails it successfully.  It also saves a copy of the pdf in the `/public/pdfs` directory.  I did make sure to include the `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));` for the static directories.  I can access the pdf's fine by directly typing it into the browser but I cannot get it automatically load after I submit it to the server.

The browser window shows:

```
Cannot GET /pdfs/2018_5_5_wj.pdf
```

The browser console shows:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Refused to apply a stylesheet because its hash, its nonce, or 'unsafe-inline' appears in neither the style-src directive nor the default-src directive of the Content Security Policy.
```

I can just refresh the page and it shows the pdf in the browser perfectly.  Is there some sort of timing issue between sending the redirect (which is instantaneous) and generating the pdf (which takes a few milliseconds)?

(client)

```
$("#testPostButton").click(function () {
    fileName = fileNamer();
    var formText = $("#formText").html();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/', 
        type: 'POST', 
        contentType: 'application/json', 
        data: JSON.stringify({formText:formText,fileName:fileName}),
        success: function(data) {
           console.log(data.fileURL);
           setTimeout(function(){window.location = data.fileURL},2000);      
        }
    });             
});
```

(server)

```
app.post('/', function (req, res) {
    //console.log(req.body);
    formText = req.body['formText'];
    fileName = req.body['fileName'];
    console.log(fileName)
    //console.log(formText);
    var wkhtmltopdf = require('wkhtmltopdf');
    options = {
        'page-size': 'Letter',
        'margin-top': '0.75in',
        'margin-right': '0.75in',
        'margin-bottom': '0.75in',
        'margin-left': '0.75in',
        'encoding': "UTF-8",
        'dpi': 800,
        'output': './public/pdfs/' + fileName,
    };
    wkhtmltopdf(formText, options);

    console.log('pdf generated');

    zipName = zipFile(fileName);
    console.log('zip generated:' + zipName);

    emailFile();


    var data = JSON.stringify({fileURL:'http://localhost:3000/pdfs/'+fileName});
    res.contentType('application/json');
    res.header('Content-Length', data.length);
    res.end(data);

});
```

Comment: JSON.stringify expects a javascript object/array....not a url

Comment: very good point....I changed it to 'var data = JSON.stringify({fileURL:'http://localhost:3000/pdfs/'+fileName});` in the server file and `success: function (data) {
            console.log(data.fileURL);
            window.location = data.fileURL;` in the client file.   That cleared up the console errors, but still get the `Cannot GET /pdfs/2018_5_5_wj.pdf` error until I refresh.

Answer (score 0):

res.header('Location', 'example.com/redirect_location');

Comment: I still get the same error.  I am really starting to think it tries to open the link a split second before the pdf is actually generated because I can just hit refresh and the PDF file is displayed perfectly.  I tried putting res.end(data) in a setTimeout for a second, but same error.

Answer (score 0):

Well, turns out it was a timing problem.  I put a 2 second timeout function around the window.location command and now it works.

`setTimeout(function(){window.location = data.fileURL},2000);`

I tried 1 second, but still got the same error, so it turns out wkhtmltopdf takes just under 2 seconds to render the file.

Comment: I feel like this isn't something that should be handled by a set timeout, rather it should be handled with a callback function to be executed once the generation completes.

Comment: I totally agree, a hacked rookie solution.  Any advice on how to do that?  I imagine a call back function would be called after the pdf is created with `wkhtmltopdf(formText, options);`.

Comment: Use an asynchronous Promise

Comment: `wkhtmltopdf` takes an optional third parameter that _is_ the callback. It accepts the stream (if you care) but you don't _have_ to do anything with it, you can just toss it and finish the rest of your code. i.e. `wkhtmltopdf(formText, options, () => { /* your code here */ })`. Give that a shot and see if it works for you.